# Diferença entre commit feito no site do github e na linha de comando

Tags: git, github

### Problema

Contribuidores diferentes para a mesma conta no repositório.

### Histórico

Quando criei o repositório, fiz upload de alguns arquivos pelo próprio site do github e os commits foram registrados como sendo meus. Porém, quando fiz commits pela linha de comando e depois fiz o push, apareceu no site do github como se fosse outra pessoa fazendo o commit. Porém é a mesma conta que fiz os uploads inicialmente.

### Suspeita

Suspeito que possa ser porque os outros commits foram "verificados" com a GPG Key do GitHub. Mas não sei o que é e até agora também não consegui enviar commits assinados pela linha de comando.

### Ilustração:

[image: Foto com alguns commits]

Comment: executa esse comando e veja se o e-mail cadastrado é o mesmo do github: `git config user.email`. Aguardo seu retorno.

Comment: No momento não teve nenhum saída porque reinstalei o Git hoje. Vou recadastrar meus dados aqui.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso pode acontecer por dois motivos:

**1º Você não definiu seu email no git**

Se for esse o caso, você precisa definir seu email em sua configuração local do git. Verifique qual é o seu email atual com

```
$ git config user.email
```

E defina seu email com

```
$ git config user.email “your.email@example.com”
```

Observe que isso afetará apenas novos commits. Commits anteriores permanecerão as mesmas.

**2º Você está usando um e-mail diferente do que foi configurado no github**

Isso acontece quando você está contribuindo para um repositório privado em um computador de trabalho, por exemplo, e você configurou o git para usar seu email de trabalho em vez do seu e-mail habitual do github.

Existem duas maneiras de corrigir isso:

- Vá para Configurações do Github> E-mails> Adicionar endereço de
  e-mail e adicione seu endereço de e-mail de trabalho aqui para vincular os
  commits feitos de um git local configurado com seu email de trabalho
  para sua conta normal do github.
- Altere sua configuração local do git para usar seu e-mail principal
  do github

Comment: Resolvido. O que estava acontecendo era a 2ª opção. Na verdade, eu estava usando uma e-mail que é sim meu, mas não estava cadastrado no github. Eu achava que esse e-mail era o do github.

De qualquer forma, muito obrigado. E desculpe-me pelo problema tão bobo.

Comment: Toda dúvida é válida, desde que seja legitima.